# Mplayer shows movie on a quarter screen only

Tags: monterey, mplayer

I just did an upgrade to MacOS 12.2.1 on a MacBook Air and now when I use mplayer to watch a video only a quarter of the area is shown. The rest is black!

Here a screenshot:

[image]

How can this be fixed so the video is shown in the full area?

The VLC player works (for most videos), but I STRONGLY would like to use `mplayer` again (as I know the shortcuts, as mplayer really seems to play every video format, and as this is one single tool to play videos!). It did work absolutely fine on MacOS 10.14.6.

I did reinstall it with the following commands:

```
brew uninstall mplayer
brew install mplayer
```

and also with

```
brew reinstall mplayer --build-from-source
```

but that did not solve the issue. Some more results:

- The issue seems to be for any video format (mp4, mkv, avi, mpg).
- The issue happens for full-screen and not full-screen.
- The issue also happens for a completely new user I created for testing this issue.

Other information and output:

```
$ system_profiler -json SPDisplayDataType
{
  "SPDisplayDataType" : [

  ]
}
```

output playing an example file with a newly compiled mplayer version 1.5:

```
$ ./mplayer ../test.mkv 
MPlayer 1.5-13.0.0 (C) 2000-2022 MPlayer Team
Can't init Apple Remote.

Playing ../test.mkv.
libavformat version 59.17.102 (internal)
libavformat file format detected.
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0
[lavf] stream 1: audio (ac3), -aid 0, -alang eng
[lavf] stream 2: subtitle (srt), -sid 0, -slang eng, English
VIDEO:  [H264]  720x480  0bpp  23.976 fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kbyte/s)
[gl] using extended formats. Use -vo gl:nomanyfmts if playback fails.
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 59.21.100 (internal)
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
==========================================================================
Clip info:
 encoder: libebml v1.0.0 + libmatroska v1.0.0
 creation_time: 2010-08-29T20:12:47.000000Z
Load subtitles in ../
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
[ac3 @ 0x101b0b890]Channel layout '5.1(side)' with 6 channels does not match specified number of channels 2: ignoring specified channel layout
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, floatle, 448.0 kbit/14.58% (ratio: 56000->384000)
Selected audio codec: [ffac3] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg AC-3)
==========================================================================
AO: [coreaudio] 48000Hz 2ch floatle (4 bytes per sample)
Starting playback...
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [gl_nosw] 720x480 => 720x542 Planar YV12 
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
A:   2.7 V:   2.7 A-V:  0.009 ct: -0.001   0/  0  6% 10%  1.0% 6 0
```

Comment: Perhaps try deleting the preference plist file under ~/Library/Preferences? Something in there might be causing the issue and most uninstalls leave preferences alone.

Comment: I do not find any `mplayer` related `plist` neither in `/Library/Preferences` nor in `~/Library/Preferences`.

Comment: I can run `mplayer -fs ...` here. Did you check (or temporarily rename) the config files mentioned in the man page to see if it depends on some settings you've changed?

Comment: As far as I can see this happens to every video. And I have removed the file `~/.mplayer`, but the issue is still the same.

Comment: Can you provide the full command that you are running, as well as the output from that command? Adding output from `system_profiler -json SPDisplaysDataType` may also help.

Comment: @n8felton I have added the additional information to my question

Comment: @Alex The fact that `SPDisplayDataType` is empty is concerning. What model Mac hardware is this running on? If it's a desktop, what monitor are you using and how is it connected - HDMI, DP?

Comment: @n8felton It's empty on my M1 Mini as well, but mplayer works as expected.

Comment: It is a MacBook Air. The display is somewhat integrated. Hardware did not change. Just the OS.