# How do I reinstall/recompile `mplayer` on MacOS 12.2.1?

Tags: macos, homebrew, open-source, mplayer

How do I reinstall/recompile `mplayer` on MacOS 12.2.1?

Since an update from version 10 to version 12 `mplayer` does not play videos correctly anymore ([Mplayer shows movie on a quarter screen only](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438169/mplayer-shows-movie-on-a-quarter-screen-only?noredirect=1&lq=1)). In order to try to fix this I want to reinstall/recompile `mplayer` and hope this will fix the problem.

But a simple

```
brew uninstall mplayer
brew install mplayer
```

did not change the behavior.

The currently installed version seems to be `MPlayer 1.5-13.0.0 (C) 2000-2022 MPlayer Team`.

So how can I reinstall/recompile `mplayer` on MacOS 12.2.1?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following `brew` options to see if that resolves the issue:

- [`brew reinstall mplayer`](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#reinstall-options-formulacask-): just a guess, but this might be more "thorough" than uninstalling and then installing.
- `brew reinstall mplayer --build-from-source`: this compiles the formula from source, takes a (very) long time, but might resolve an issue with your specific machine.