# How to fix "undefined symbols" for compiling mplayer

Tags: macos, homebrew, open-source, mplayer

When I try to compile mplayer on MacOS (12.4) I get an error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_x264_encoder_open_163", referenced from:
      _X264_init in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_x264_encoder_open_163", referenced from:
      _X264_init in libavcodec.a(libx264.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mencoder] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mplayer] Error 1
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

I did run just

```
./configure
```

before that.

Comment: Looks like libavcodec is missing a dependency, possibly x264? Either the dependency isn't installed, or the build system otherwise cannot find it.

Comment: I tried to reinstall x264 using `brew reinstall x264` but the compilation of `mplayer` resulted in the same error message.

Comment: If you're compiling mplayer via homebrew, that sounds like a bug you should report to homebrew. If not, you need to figure out why mplayer and/or libavcodec can't find x264.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Not sure how to do that. I tried `brew install libav` but `libav` seems outdated, also several suggested `configure` options do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

[For some reasons unknown to me a first reinstall](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/438504) of `x264` did not work. But when (after some other attempts to install what is missing) I did *again*

```
brew reinstall x264
```

something was compiled. But then I did run the following three commands in exactly this order:

```
./configure
make clean
make
```

And to my total surprise it did compile finally `mplayer`. And it works (and fixes a bug only I seem to have).